# How to do a exists query on many to many relationships

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, hql

I have this query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM   A a 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   AB m 
                   WHERE  m.a_id = a.id 
                          AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                      FROM   B b 
                                      WHERE  m.b_id = b.id 
                                             AND b.TYPE = 'C'))
```

I need to  write this in Hql.

I have already mapped the many to many relationship in the `AEntity` and `BEntity` classes such that `AEntity` has `linkedBs` and `BEntity` has `linkedAs`

I want a less verbose version for this query.

**EDIT**

The thing is that We do not have any hibernate entity for the table `AB` as it is just a JoinTable. So please provide a way to write this query without using table AB explicitly.

Comment: Please post a data set and a wished result set

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You can use a cartesian product between entityA and entityB and then you'll check if not exists this couple in the middle table

```
SELECT a
FROM entityA a, entityB b
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'couple'
    FROM ab m
    WHERE m.id = a.id AND m.id = b.id)
```

Comment: That does not give me the same result